# ServiceUnavailableException with LDAP and JNDI

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ldap, jndi

I am using JNDI to connect to LDAP and I need it to work with many simultaneous TCP connections. All connections need to be established at the same time. The mystery is that sometimes it works and sometimes it establishes just some connections e.g. 17 of 30.
I saw similar problems by googling but nobody provided their solution. Thanks!
Stack trace:

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: 172.16.0.xxx:389; socket closed
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:464)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:370)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:222)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2752)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:328)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:205)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:223)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:166)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:96)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:695)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:253)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:227)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:112)
```

EDIT: some code

```
socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
is = socket.getInputStream();
os = socket.getOutputStream();
bif = new BufferedInputStream(is);
bof = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, usr);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");
env.put("java.naming.ldap.derefAliases", "never");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap:// /*address*/);
try {
    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);//ERROR
} catch (ServiceUnavailableException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("service unavailable");
}
```

Comment: Post some code. This indicates a progamming error on your part somewhere.

Comment: 1. What's the socket for? 2. Where do you close the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share that the problem was with limited file descriptors on ldap server and after raising the limit it works fine.

Comment: Unlikely. More likely you are leaking connections somewhere. All you've done is change the point where the problem occurs. You didn't answer any of the questions you were asked. The `Socket` for example is completely pointless.

Comment: This is, of course, not the whole code. I put it just to show the line where the error occurred. Socket is used to transfer messages to ldap server. Input and output streams, sockets, context, etc, are properly closed and there is no leakage (checked with visualvm). At first I thought it was the waiting time or something like that. On the ldap server with netstat I saw ~1000 connections when errors occoured and default FD value is 1024(and yes there were this many connections actually). Sorry for the confusion I thought sb with ldap experience had similar issue with many tcp connections.

Comment: No. Messages are transferred to the LDAP server by calling methods on `Contexts.` The `Socket` has nothing to do with it. You should be able to see for yourself, as it isn't *used* anywhere. If that's what you think it's for, you *must remove it:* you are wasting resources at the LDAP server.